# django : OneToOne field links to id and not to email

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, one-to-one

**How to change the linking of OneToOne Field**

See the bottom for my problems

**Output in terminal :**

```
In [21]: profile = User.objects.get(email='jlennon@beatles.com')
In [22]: profile
Out[22]: <User: jlennon@beatles.com>

In [23]: profile = User.objects.get(email='jlennon@beatles.com').profile

In [24]: profile
Out[24]: <Users: Aniket>
In [25]: profile = User.objects.get(id=2).profile

In [26]: profile
Out[26]: <Users: Aniket>

In [27]: User.objects.get(id=2)
Out[27]: <User: jlennon@beatles.com>

In [28]: User.objects.get(id=4)
Out[28]: <User: AniketYadav>
```

**models.py :**

```
class Users(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
    user_Id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    user_fname = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)
    user_lname = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)
    user_email = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    user_password = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    joining_date = models.DateTimeField()
    user_dob = models.DateField()
    user_country = models.CharField(max_length=3, blank=True, null=True)
    user_gender = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    user_pic = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    user_about = models.CharField(max_length=512, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Users'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Users'
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tbl_users'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_name
```

**settings.py**

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'myWebsite.Users'
```

**my database :**

```
mysql> select id, username, email from auth_user where id=1 or id=2 or id=4;
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | username            | email               |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | admin               | admin@admin.com     |
|  2 | jlennon@beatles.com | jlennon@beatles.com |
|  4 | AniketYadav         | aniket@gmail.com    |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**My Users table (tbl_users):**

```
+---------+-----------+------------------------------+
| user_id | user_name | user_email                   |
+---------+-----------+------------------------------+
|       2 | Aniket    | aniket@gmail.com             |
|       3 | Crazy     | crazy@crazy.com              |
+---------+-----------+------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

### I did this but in vain

New **Users** class as suggested to change

```
class Users(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
    user_Id = models.IntegerField()
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    user_fname = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)
    user_lname = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)
    user_email = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=60)
    user_password = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    joining_date = models.DateTimeField()
    user_dob = models.DateField()
    user_country = CountryField()
    user_gender = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    user_pic = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    user_about = models.CharField(max_length=512, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Users'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Users'
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tbl_users'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_name
```

**MySQL table Description**:

```
mysql> desc tbl_users;
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+------------------------------+-------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default                      | Extra |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+------------------------------+-------+
| user_id       | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL                         |       |
| user_name     | varchar(25)  | NO   |     | NULL                         |       |
| user_fname    | varchar(40)  | YES  |     | NULL                         |       |
| user_lname    | varchar(40)  | YES  |     | NULL                         |       |
| user_email    | varchar(60)  | NO   | PRI | NULL                         |       |
| user_password | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL                         |       |
| joining_date  | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL                         |       |
| user_dob      | date         | NO   |     | NULL                         |       |
| user_country  | varchar(3)   | YES  |     | NULL                         |       |
| user_gender   | char(1)      | NO   |     | NULL                         |       |
| user_pic      | char(255)    | YES  |     | ../images/provideAnImage.jpg |       |
| user_about    | varchar(512) | YES  |     | NULL                         |       |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+------------------------------+-------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**But still the output which I am getting is :**

```
In [4]: User.objects.get(email='aniket@gmail.com').profile
Out[4]: <Users: Apurva>
In [5]: User.objects.get(email='jlennon@beatles.com')
Out[5]: <User: jlennon@beatles.com>

In [6]: User.objects.get(email='jlennon@beatles.com').profile
Out[6]: <Users: Aniket>
```

Comment: There is no problem here whatsover. you are free to display whatever field from the model that you want.

Comment: @e4c5 That is what I know but the problem is linking of profile with user_id instead of user_email

Comment: what does that mean?

Comment: @e4c5 That means for email='aniket@gmail.com' , I should get the profile of **Aniket** but I'm getting the profile of **Apurva**

Comment: Why are you duplicating the email field in myWebsite.Users? that and some other fields too.

Comment: @e4c5 Actually it's from my earlier PHP version of the website , which I didn't care to drop as of now but would soon do the beneficial

Comment: sorry but the problem is in your table structure. No point in trying to fix that in your code

Comment: @e4c5 So what do you sugggest I should do ? In the meantime I dropped the password and email columns

Answer (score 0):

There Is One solution for this you can make the `email`,

in your project root directory, you can see `__init__.py` add the following code.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
User._meta.get_field('email')._unique = True
```

Comment: can you explain ... what it is supposed to do

Comment: it will make email as unique , if you try to add same email id it will throw the exception.

Comment: That is not what I want ... I want linking of id in **User** table to email in **tbl_users** table

Answer (score 0):

You could reach or modify user email while registering. As this article says https://django.cowhite.com/blog/customizing-user-details-user-models-and-authentication/

```
def register(request):
# Validate the user registration data
if userForm.is_valid():
    email = userForm.cleaned_data['email']
    username = userForm.cleaned_data['username']
    password = userForm.cleaned_data['password']
    user = User.objects.create_user(email=email, username=username, password=password)
    # Then save the profile details
    dob = userForm.cleaned_data['date_of_birth']
    department = userForm.cleaned_data['department']
    profile = Profile.objects.create(user=user, date_of_birth=dob, department=department)
```